# Replace string with np.nan if condition is met

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to replace a string occurrence in a column if a condition is met.

My sample input dataset:

```
Series Name     Type  
Food            ACG
Drinks          FEG
Food at Home    BON
```

I want to replace the strings on the Series Name column if the strings on the Type column are either ACG or BON with nan or blank. For that I tried the following code where I used conditions with not much success.

Code:

```
df.loc[((df['Type'] == 'ACG') | (df['Type'] == 'BON')),
                df['Series Name'].replace(np.nan)]
```

Desired output:

```
Series Name     Type  
                ACG
                FEG
Food at Home    BON
```

Comment: Try replacing it with `None` instead of `np.nan` and see if it works.

Comment: @ARK1375 It, didn't unfortunately.

Comment: Your code doesn't replace anything: it just accesses `df` by using `df.loc`: see the square brackets `[]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you want to set the whole cell to nan, just do this:

```
df.loc[((df['Type'] == 'ACG') | (df['Type'] == 'BON')), 'Series Name'] = np.nan
```

Output:

```
  Series Name Type
0         NaN  ACG
1      Drinks  FEG
2         NaN  BON
```

**Update**:
Regarding to your question in the comments, if you only wanted to change parts of the string, you could use `replace` like this:

```
#new input
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Series Name': ['Food to go', 'Fast Food', 'Food at Home'], 
    'Type': ['ACG', 'FEG', 'BON']
})

    Series Name Type
0    Food to go  ACG
1     Fast Food  FEG
2  Food at Home  BON

mask = df['Type'].isin(['ACG', 'BON'])
df.loc[mask, 'Series Name'] = (df.loc[mask, 'Series Name']
                               .replace(to_replace="Food", value='NEWVAL', regex=True))
print(df)

      Series Name Type
0    NEWVAL to go  ACG
1       Fast Food  FEG
2  NEWVAL at Home  BON
```

Comment: Gotta ask, what do you mean by "set the whole cell to nan" exactly?

Comment: What I meant was, you don't want to replace parts of the string, instead you want to replace the whole string which is in that row

Comment: updated my post. Maybe it gets more clear then

Comment: No problem, that's what I thought you meant but I just wanted to make sure. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use [`Series.mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html):

```
mask = df['Type'].isin(['ACG', 'BON'])
df['Series Name'] = df['Series Name'].mask(mask)
```

Output:

```
 Series Name Type
0         NaN  ACG
1      Drinks  FEG
2         NaN  BON
```